# Как переслать всю почту на одну почту?

Tags: sendmail

Я работаю над временной службой электронной почты (или «одноразовой» электронной почтой), и я выполнил всю необходимую работу для нее. Тем не менее, у меня возникли трудности с пересылкой электронных писем, созданных клиентами, предполагаемому получателю. Не могли бы вы оказать помощь в том, как переслать почтовый адрес, созданный клиентами, предполагаемому получателю?

Comment: Ваш самопиар конечно интересен, но все же, вопросу не хватает конкретики

Comment: поищите mail forwarding smtp

Comment: Я снова убрал ваши ссылки. Если опять вернете, я буду расценивать ваш вопрос как спам-сообщение.